# sql server joining two set of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following simple (i think) requirement:

Have one value lets say '1', then I have a table with one column which has more than one row.

What is the SQL required so that I return two columns, the first column having all values of '1', the second column being the values from the table.

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 1 as yourValue, yourField from yourTable
```

that ?

edit:

Even more, if it's a value coming as parameter (in a variable) you could do the same

```
select @yourVariable as yourValue, yourField from yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `SELECT` the value as a column like so:

```
SELECT '1', col1, ... FROM tbl
```